# How can i read a .docx or .doc file directly from the URL link without downloading it to the local system in Python 3.7?

Tags: docx, python-3.7

I have built a resume parsing code in Python 3.7 but i want to read a .docx or .doc resume file directly from the URL link(e.g. http://13.234.163.240/storage/userData/phpjsK4iJ.docx) without downloading it to my local system.

Answer (score 0):

How about Requests?

```py
import requests
from io import BytesIO

r = requests.get('http://your.link/storage/file.docx')
fh = BytesIO(r.content)

your_resume_parser.parse_resume(fh)
```

More about Requests: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: thanks for you reply, however my parser can parse the string. I can extract the pdfs as string but using the bytesIo object I am unable to get a string